# Not able to disable 1Password extension on input fields

Tags: html, angular, typescript, 1password

I have a form, with some simple input fields. In some of them the 1Password Extension gets triggered and the popup shows up.

[image]

And in some cases the popup does not get triggered.

I can't find any reason why it would trigger on these specific input fields.

HTML of Input where 1Password gets triggered.

```
<div class="col">
  <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="form-mat-field mt-1 mx-auto">
     <mat-label class="form-control-label"
      jhiTranslate="bringCockpitApp.sponsoredProduct.fadeoutIconId">
      Fadeout Icon Key
      </mat-label>
      <input formControlName="fadeoutIconId" matInput name="fadeoutIconId"
                                           placeholder="Bier"
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Any idea, why this is happening? and how to disable it?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

put data-1p-ignore as an attribute in your field to get 1Password to ignore the field.

```
<input type="text" id="username" name="ig" data-1p-ignore>
```

Source: https://developer.1password.com/docs/web/compatible-website-design